# Delta compression in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compression, signal-processing

I tried delta compression in MATLAB. I tried to use array instead of for loop but encountered a problem during the decompression. No syntax errors but not able to get back the original stream. Please help me. Here is my code:

```
clear all;
close all;
m = [20,3,55,11,222,555,6,98,0,46];
subplot(3,1,1);plot(m);title('Raw Data');
delta(1) = m(1);
i = [1:(length(m)-1)];
delta(i+1) = m(i+1)-m(i);
subplot(3,1,2);plot(delta);title('Delta Encoding')
j =[1:(length(delta)-1)];
delta_decode(1) = delta(1);
delta_decode(j+1)=delta(j+1)+delta(j);
subplot(3,1,3);plot(delta_decode);title('Delta Decoding')
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, have you really tried to run this code? It gives an error as `delta_decode(j)+delta(j)` can not be evaluated because `delta_decode(j)` is not defined for `j >1`. Nevertheless have you tried to do the following: `delta_decode=cumsum(delta)`

Comment: Thank You, I changed {delta_decode(j)+delta(j)} to {delta_decode(j+1)=delta(j+1)+delta(j);} Can you please help me out?

Comment: Thank you about cumsum(delta). I tried and it worked. But, can you please show me what error I'm doing in my method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So why is your decoding not working, lets have a look on the math

Lets assume we have a sequence of `N` numbers `X1,X2,...,XN`

The variable delta holds the following information

```
delta= delta(1), delta(2),delta(3), ...,delta(N)
delta= X1      , X2-X1   , X3-X2  , ..., XN - X(N-1)
```

So what you are doing right now is to add always two entries which will result in the following:

```
delta(1)+delta(2), delta(2)+delta(3), delta(3)+delta(4)
X1+X2-X1,          X2-X1+X3-X2,       X3-X2+X4-X3,...
```

Summarizing it:

```
X2, X3-X1, X4-X2
```

So you see this not what you want, to restore / decode the real values you need the accumulation of all previous information. Thats why you have to add everything

This means:

```
X2= X1 + delta(2)=X1+X2-X1=X2
X3= X1 + delta(2)+delta(3)=X2+delta(3)=X2+X3-X2=X3
X4= X1 + delta(2)+delta(3)+delta(4)=X2+delta(3)+delta(4)=X3 +delta(4)=X3+X4-X3=X4
and so on ...
```

As mentioned in the comments, you can achieve that without a for-loop by using `cumsum(delta)`